# How to plot only one half of a scatter matrix using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using pandas scatter_matrix (couldn't get PairgGrid in seaborn to work) to plot all combinations of a set of columns in a pandas frame. Each column as 1000 data points and there are nine columns.

I am using the following code:

```
pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(8,8))
```

I get the figure shown below:

[image]

This is nice., However, you'll notice that across the main diagonal I have a mirror image. Is it possible to plot only the lower portion as in the following fake plot I made using paint:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is probably not the cleanest way to do it, but it works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
axes = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris, alpha=0.2, figsize=(8,8))

for i in range(np.shape(axes)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(axes)[1]):
        if i < j:
            axes[i,j].set_visible(False)
```

[image]